# Typescript interface generic property names

Tags: typescript, interface, properties, typescript-typings

Say we have two variables

`const x='property1'
const y='property2'`

and we have function

```
function foo<key extends keyof MapInterface>(name: key, props: (MapInterface[key]))
```

This interface should look like

```
interface MapInterface{
'property1':any;
'property2':any;
}
```

Is it possible to have the interface be generically created like by calling the variables x,y

```
interface MapInterface{
x:any; //return 'property1':any;
y:any; //return 'property2':any;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#constant-named-properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript interface, using string constants for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608338/typescript-interface-using-string-constants-for-properties)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript interface, using string constants for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608338/typescript-interface-using-string-constants-for-properties)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this as of TypeScript 2.7, with [constant-named properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#constant-named-properties), introduced in pull request [Microsoft/TypeScript#15473](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15473).  The only thing you are missing is that you need to use [computed property syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (the property name must be encased in brackets):

```
const x = 'property1'
const y = 'property2';

interface MapInterface {
  [x]: any;
  [y]: any;
} 

declare const mapInt: MapInterface;
mapInt[x]; // works      
mapInt[y]; // works
mapInt.property1; // also works
mapInt.property2; // also works
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: The problem is x and y are being imported from a separate class, thus the values will be accessible to the interface on runtime and not compile time. So it, unfortunately, rejects this approach.

Comment: You should be able to access them in a separate class at compile time, but of course I don't know your setup... and you should edit your question with relevant information if you want a more targeted answer; the answer above does apply to your question as it is currently stated.