# Computed properties using string enum in Typescript interface inaccessible with dot notation

Tags: typescript

I feel like this question is similar to this one: [Typescript interface, using string constants for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608338/typescript-interface-using-string-constants-for-properties) but I want to confirm this behavior anyway.

Say you have:

```
enum AcmeFields {
  ID = 'id',
  NAME = 'companyName',
}
```

and then an `interface`:

```
interface AcmeInterface {
  [AcmeFields.ID]: string,
  [AcmeFields.NAME]?: string;
}
```

with say this:
`const sampleCompany: AcmeInterface = { id: 1, name: 'Sample Company' }`

Why am I only able to do this? (Typescript provides autocomplete for this)

```
sampleCompany['id']
sampleCompany[AcmeFields.ID]
sampleCompany['companyName']
sampleCompany[AcmeFields.NAME]
```

and not this? (no autocomplete or recognition)

```
sampleCompany.id
sampleCompany.companyName
```

Comment: I think this is related to a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25323)... but not sure if this exact issue is covered

Answer (score 1):

Because your enum expression compiles to JavaScript which defines an object with properties `ID` and `NAME`, essentially like this:

```
var AcmeFields = {
    ID: "id",
    NAME: "name"    
};
```

Given that, it should be clear why you need to use `ID` and `NAME` to access the enum members: `"id"` and `"name"` are very much the values, not the properties, of the resulting object. (You can verify this by looking at your compiled JavaScript, or in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20AcmeFields%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20ID%20%3D%20'id'%2C%0D%0A%20%20NAME%20%3D%20'companyName'%2C%0D%0A%7D).)

So when you write any of the following:

```
sampleCompany['id']
sampleCompany[AcmeFields.ID]
sampleCompany['name']
sampleCompany[AcmeFields.NAME]
```

you are writing expressions to dynamically access the properties of an object using strings. All these will return `undefined`. TypeScript allows such access without compile errors but it does not mean the expressions are useful. You should instead access your enum values in the form `AcmeFields.ID`, or if you need to, `AcmeFields[ "ID" ]`.

It is only when the enum members are numeric that the TypeScript compiler assigns the "reverse mapping", so if you had:

```
enum AcmeNumbers {
    FIRST = 1,
    THIRD = 3    
};
```

Then both `AcmeNumbers.FIRST` and `AcmeNumbers[1]` give `1`.

Because of the potential confusion with string enums, in general I would recommend to defining string enums with their property names the same as their values.